# Bone creation in XNA Content Pipeline

Tags: xna, xna-content-pipeline, skeletal-animation

I'm trying to manually create a `ModelContent` instance that includes custom Bone data in a custom `ContentProcessor` in the XNA Content Pipeline. I can't seem to create or assign manually created bone data due to either private constructors or read-only collections (at every turn).

The code I have right now that creates a single triangle `ModelContent` that I'd like to create a bone for is:

```
MeshContent mc = new MeshContent();
mc.Positions.Add(new Vector3(-10, 0, 0));
mc.Positions.Add(new Vector3(0, 10, 0));
mc.Positions.Add(new Vector3(10, 0, 0));

GeometryContent gc = new GeometryContent();
gc.Indices.AddRange(new int[] { 0, 1, 2 });
gc.Vertices.AddRange(new int[] { 0, 1, 2 });
mc.Geometry.Add(gc);

// Create normals
MeshHelper.CalculateNormals(mc, true);

// finally, convert it to a model
ModelContent model = context.Convert<MeshContent, ModelContent>(mc, "ModelProcessor");
```

The documentation on XNA is amazingly sparse. I've been referencing the class diagrams created by [DigitalRune](https://web.archive.org/web/20210225045526/http://www.digitalrune.com/Support/Blog/tabid/719/EntryId/49/XNA-4-0-Class-Diagrams.aspx) and [Sean Hargreaves blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309211619/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/), but I haven't found anything on creating bone content.

Once the `ModelContent` is created, it's not possible to add bones because the `Bones` collection is read-only. And it seems the only way to create the `ModelContent` instance is to call the standard `ModelProcessor` via `ContentProcessorContext.Convert`. So it's a bit of a catch-22.

The `BoneContent` class has a constructor but no methods except those inherited from `NodeContent`... though now (true to form) maybe I've realized the solution by asking the question. Should I create a root `NodeContent` with two children: one `MeshContent` and one `BoneContent` as the root of my skeleton; then pass the root `NodeContent` to `ContentProcessorContext.Convert`?

Comment: Solved. Answer to be posted after 9pm tonight due to new account reputation. In an nutshell, every design-time NodeContent instance gets a unique ModelBone at run-time. Details to come.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

A bone will be created for each `NodeContent` whether it is a `BoneContent` or a `MeshContent`. In the former case, it appears the intention of the `BoneContent` class is simply to indicate that the node is a bone *only*. The bone hierarchy at runtime will match this build time `NodeContent` hierarchy.

In my simple case, the solution was simply

```
MeshContent mc = new MeshContent();
... create mesh ...

mc.Transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0,10.0f,0);

// NOTE: type parameter has changed from MeshContent to NodeContent
ModelContent model = context.Convert<NodeContent, ModelContent>(mc, "ModelProcessor");
```

which creates a single bone at runtime. For a more complicated hierarchy I could do something like:

```
BoneContent turtle = new BoneContent();
MeshContent body = new MeshContent();
MeshContent head = new MeshContent();
MeshContent eye = new MeshContent();

turtle.Children.Add(body)
body.Children.Add(head);
head.Children.Add(eye);

head.Transform = ...;
body.Transform = ...;
eye.Transform = ...;

// create the one-eyed turtle
ModelContent model = context.Convert<NodeContent, ModelContent>(turtle, "ModelProcessor");
```

which would have 4 bones at runtime arranged in the chain: `turtle->body->head->eye`.

To assist in debugging, I found it useful to set the `Name` property (from `ContentItem`) at build time, then check `Model.Root.Index` and `Model.Root.Name` against the `Model.Bones` list.

Comment: Great work. Please mark this answer as correct when you get the chance.

Comment: Will do. Stackexchange is enforcing the 24-hour delay on marking my own answer as correct. One hour to go.